# Angular | Update mat-table with new data array with filter

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, filter, mat-table

I am using a filter to only display data in a mat-table according to the filter.

In my case I have a mat-table where I inject an array with objects in it.

The function when I am filtering my data array:

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {MatTable} from '@angular/material';

@ViewChild('TABLE') table: MatTable<any>;

dataSource: CandidateDataSource | null;


filterTableFunction(form) {

   let result = this.dataSource.data.filter(obj => {

        if (form.userValidation === true) {
            return obj.candidateState === 'userValidation';
        }

    });

    this.dataSource.filteredData = [...this.result];
    this.table.renderRows();

    console.log('I am new datasource', this.dataSource.filteredData);
    console.log('I am result', result);
 }
```

From my console, I can see that the new filtered array is correct, however my table does not update with the new array.

I have also tried making "result" a global variable, with no luck.

EDIT:

First answer did unfortunately not solve my problem.

New code:

```
// public
public result = [];

filterTableFunction(form) {

     console.log('#1', this.dataSource.data); //logs an array of objects

    this.result = this.dataSource.data.filter(obj => {

            if (form.userValidation === true) {
            return obj.candidateState === 'userValidation';
        }

   });

   console.log('#2' , this.result); // New array containing the objects with candidateState === 'userValidation'

    this.dataSource.data = [...this.result];

    this.table.renderRows();

   console.log('#3', this.dataSource.data) // Shows replaced array from above line with the correct result

 }
```

[image: Screenshot of logs]

Comment: Could you please say where you are logging the output?

Comment: @MichaelD I updated my post. Is this an answer to your question?

Comment: I also see you've replaced `this.result = [...this.dataSource.data]` with `this.dataSource.filteredData = [...this.result];`. Could you please post the code where `result` is used to update the table?

Comment: @MichaelD see new edit

Comment: In that case, you might need to post more information. Could you please post the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from MichealID's answer, I got the following solution:

Filter function in component.ts

```
public result = [];


async submitFilter(form) {

    this.result = this.dataSource.filteredData.filter(obj => {
        if (form.userValidation === true) {
            return obj.candidateState === 'userValidation';
        }

    });

    const resultValues = this.result.map(r => r.candidateState);

    this.dataSource.filter = resultValues[0];

    console.log(this.dataSource.filteredData);
}
```

In my datasource.ts:

```
 // Private
 private _filterChange = new BehaviorSubject('');
 private _filteredDataChange = new BehaviorSubject('');

 constructor( private _candidateService: CandidateService){
    this.filteredData = this._candidateService.candidateData;
 }

// Filtered data
get filteredData(): any {
    return this._filteredDataChange.value;
}

set filteredData(value: any) {
    this._filteredDataChange.next(value);
}

// Filter
get filter(): string {
    return this._filterChange.value;
}

set filter(filter: string) {
    this._filterChange.next(filter);
}

filterData(data): any {
    if (!this.filter) {
        return data;
    }
    return FuseUtils.filterArrayByString(data, this.filter);
}
```

So, I'm on deep water here, but I made the "hack" to get the value candidateState on my array and take that string value into my filter, which would then filter out all objects containing that value. I don't think this is a good solution, since I can only check on one thing here, and not multiple filters like "candidateState" and example "salary". I does work for now and displays me all objects with the value I wished for. Thank you MichealID for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. `result` variable is overwritten with old values.
2. Spread operator may not be required since `this.dataSource.data` is already an array.

Please try the following

```js
filterTableFunction(form) {
  const result = this.dataSource.data.filter(
    obj => { 
      if (form.userValidation === true) {
        return obj.candidateState === 'userValidation';
      }  
    }
  );

  this.table.renderRows();
}
```

If you need to construct an array of values of the `candidateState` key from the object, you could use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
// resultValues = ['userValidation', 'userValidation', 'userValidation', ...]
const resultValues = result.map(r => r.candidateState);
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tqp6lt)